# How do i wait for a program to open before executing rest of code

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that opens a specific program, then waits for it to open after that pyautogui types my email and password, my problem is sometimes the program takes a while and i currently use a set time before the rest of the code is executed

```
if wsws == 'l':
        
        os.startfile(r'C:\Users\file.lnk')
        time.sleep(10)
        pag.click(560, 540)
        time.sleep(1)
        pag.press('tab')
        if aob.lower() == 'a':
            pag.typewrite('username')
            time.sleep(0.2)
            pag.press('tab')
            pag.typewrite('password')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            pag.press('enter')
```

sometimes the program opens before the 10 seconds or far after

Comment: hi MoistDankFedora! Welcome to SO!

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Try with `Popen` from the `subprocess` module instead

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does "wait for it to open" mean? When a program starts, a lot of things could happen. How should your script know that the other GUI program is *ready* for the pyautogui input? In other words, when you ask "my problem is sometimes the program takes a while" - takes a while **to do exactly what**?

Comment: by open i mean that the program's ui is on screen and i can interact with elements of it